# Getting HTTP Status 404 – Not Found : The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, restful-url

I was following this tutorial on RESTful Web Services https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm
I've followed the same steps but the resource is not being found when I hit the URI through postman http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users

This is web.xml file stored inside WEB-INF folder under web app, the rest of the files have same content of the tutorial, I'm a bit new to web services please help with what could be going wrong here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <display-name>User Management</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.tutorialspoint</param-value>
      </init-param>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Server - apache-tomcat-10.1.10

Jersey - 2.40.0

Jdk 19

UserService

```
package com.tutorialspoint;  

import java.util.List; 
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  
@Path("/UserService") 

public class UserService {  
   UserDao userDao = new UserDao();  
   @GET 
   @Path("/users") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
   public List<User> getUsers(){ 
       System.out.println("Inside Service Class");
      return userDao.getAllUsers(); 
   }  
}
```

User

```
package com.tutorialspoint;  

import java.io.Serializable;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement; 
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement; 
@XmlRootElement(name = "user") 

public class User implements Serializable {  
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
   private int id; 
   private String name; 
   private String profession;  
   public User(){} 
    
   public User(int id, String name, String profession){  
      this.id = id; 
      this.name = name; 
      this.profession = profession; 
   }  
   public int getId() { 
      return id; 
   }  
   @XmlElement 
   public void setId(int id) { 
      this.id = id; 
   } 
   public String getName() { 
      return name; 
   } 
   @XmlElement
   public void setName(String name) { 
      this.name = name; 
   } 
   public String getProfession() { 
      return profession; 
   } 
   @XmlElement 
   public void setProfession(String profession) { 
      this.profession = profession; 
   }   
}
```

UserDao

```
package com.tutorialspoint;  

import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.ObjectInputStream; 
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;  

public class UserDao { 
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<User> getAllUsers(){ 
      
      List<User> userList = null; 
      try { 
         File file = new File("Users.dat"); 
         if (!file.exists()) { 
            User user = new User(1, "Mahesh", "Teacher"); 
            userList = new ArrayList<User>(); 
            userList.add(user); 
            saveUserList(userList); 
         } 
         else{ 
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); 
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis); 
            userList = (List<User>) ois.readObject(); 
            ois.close(); 
         } 
      } catch (IOException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }   
      return userList; 
   } 
   private void saveUserList(List<User> userList){ 
      try { 
         File file = new File("Users.dat"); 
         FileOutputStream fos;  
         fos = new FileOutputStream(file); 
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos); 
         oos.writeObject(userList); 
         oos.close(); 
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } catch (IOException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } 
   }    
}
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQchU.png)

[Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl4Ff.png)

Also, getting this exception for the first time when I hit the URI

```
Message Class [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer] is not a Servlet

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Class [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer] is not a Servlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:676)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet (org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @a82c5f1; jakarta.servlet.Servlet is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @3b95a09c)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:676)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

Am I messing up with the versions?

Comment: I doubt _everything_ is the same if it doesn't work. Find out what's different. You've provided one file from the entire article, and haven't provided other details like server, jars, folder structure. So with this little information you've provided, the best we can say is for you to figure out what's different from the article

Comment: Hello, you have: `<url-pattern>/rest/</url-pattern>` and in original it is: `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: @Mar-Z It's resulting in the same error with the original <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> pattern too.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I've updated the required details in the post.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I messing up with the versions?

Yes, the Jersey version 2.40 won't work with Tomcat 10.1 Try Jersey 3.1.2 instead.

Comment: While it resolved the class cast exception, the 404 not found is still being thrown when I hit the URI